# Recover from wrong commit message [git bash on windows]?

Tags: git, git-bash

[image]

When i was writing the message then `enter` button suddenly press so how do i exit from it?

I've tried `Q` but nothing came out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the message, if you forgot to do so you need to type this:

<kbd>CTRL + C</kbd>

[image]

---

Another option is to use <kbd>CTRL + D</kbd> but this will display error message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to click Ctrl+C.
Another option is to close the quote (type **"**) and press Enter, and then to overwrite the commit message by running:

```
git commit --amend -m "<message>"
```

Where `<message>` is the correct message you want to insert